# iOS 5 Storyboard: NavigationViewController to TabbarController - Not working , Why?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I am using iOS5 with Storyboard and my scenes are like this :

NavigationCOntroller ->(Nav view 1) TableViewController -> TabBarController ->(Tab1)TableViewController
and similarly I more tabs under my TabBarController.

Now I go to Tab1 when user clicks on any row in my TableViewCOntroller and before PerformingSegue I want to send some data to my Tab1(TableViewController) like this

```
MyTableVController *tvc = segue.destinationViewController;
tvc.selectedObject =  currentObject;
```

[UITabBarController setSelectedObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c9450

Now why is it assuming that 'MyTableVController' is  a UITabBarController and searching for setSelectedObject method ???

And how can I pass data to my TableViewCOntroller in this scenario ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I have found solution to my problem , I did like this

```
UITabBarController *tabController  = (UITabBarController *)segue.destinationViewController;
     MyTableVController *tvc = (MyTableVController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

And thats how you have your required viewcontroller and pass data to it.

Comment: When I put `UITabBarController *tabController  = (UITabBarController *)segue.destinationViewController;` in, it said that it didn't like 'segue.'?